# javascript/jquery : force browser to fullscreen on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, fullscreen

I am writing a web app for a specific android device. This "website" schould be displayed in fullscreen mode.

I found the code above here in stack overflow and it works fine with an click event, although the page should automaticaly open and stay in fullscreen when I am entering the site.

I understand the code, but the load event does not work. Is there any way, javascript, jquery to archieve this goal?

```
<script>
var el = document.documentElement,
rfs = el.requestFullscreen
      || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
      || el.mozRequestFullScreen
      || el.msRequestFullscreen
      ;
     rfs.call(el);
</script>
```

Comment: use the document ready event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching a website in fullscreen can be archieved via Google's web app feature and Chrome mobile.

Add this to your :

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="ico_lg.png">
```

**And finally the manifest.json explanation by Mozilla**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json

**Here are some other tipps from Google regarding full screen mode:**
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Answer (score 1):

The javascript fullscreen API can only be invoked by a user interaction, like a mouse/pointer click.

The reason being protecting the end-user from invasive websites. like for example, entering fullscreen or locking the pointer(on a pc) when opening the site.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @MarLon, if this answers your question (which I think it does), you can "accept" it and close the question by clicking the arrow next to the answer. Have a look at [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/174723) for more details about why it's a good idea to accept answers.